# How to display active actionlink in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I have some actionlinks in my _Layout.cshtml view as follows:

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Signup", "Signup", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

I want to show `Signup` action link in another color when it is selected.
how can I do this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: *selected* means when the user is on `Signup` page or when clicking on `Signup` link?

Comment: user is in Signup page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the values contained in ViewContext.RouteData, namely the Action and Controller values. We could build on what you currently have with something like this

```
  <li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Signup" ? "active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Signup", "Signup", "Home")</li>
  <li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Login" ? "active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
  <li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

if you need controller means just check the condition

```
<li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Home" ? "active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign some class to action link to give different color, you can give different style for [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) etc.

Html

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Signup", "Signup", 
     new { controller = "Home", id = 1 }, 
     new { @class = "anchor-class" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

CSS

```
.anchor-class 
{
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, quick way is to have something to signal which page user is on like `ViewBag.IsSignupPage` and then use this flag to mark active/inactive class on links:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Signup", "Signup", "Home", 
   new {@class=((ViewBag.IsSignupPage??false)?"signup-highlight":"normal-link")})</li>
```

You may have some common code to identify current view and highlight related link accordingly. You can use `ViewContext` to get current *action* and *controller* in `_layout.cshtml` to use across pages.

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```